# how does .isdigit() work in this case?

Tags: python, string, sum, digits

When I was looking for a solution for the problem "count digits in a given string containing both letters and digits" there was one with built-in function .isdigit(). Here it is:

```
def count_numbers1(a):
    return sum(int(x) for x in a if x.isdigit())
```

It works nicely but I cannot get how it works. I have read that the `.isdigit()` returns true if there is at least one digit in a string false otherwise.

And one more question: how the function "takes out" the digits from the string and converts it in integers and how it skips the letters? Why `int(x)` when `x` is a letter does not produce an error? such as:

```
>>> int('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 1, in <module>
     int('a')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Comment: _I have read that the .isdigit() returns true if there is at least one digit in a string_ That's wrong.  Where did you read that?

Comment: [link]https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm. Probably I misunderstood it

Comment: The _very first sentence_ on that page: "The method isdigit() checks whether the string consists of digits only".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the function doesn't *count* digits in a string. It *sums up* the digits in a string. Secondly, `str.isdigit()` only returns true if **all** characters in a string are digits, not just one of the characters. From the [`str.isdigit()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

> Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

This means `'1a'.isdigit()` is false, because there is a non-digit character in that string. Iteration over a string produces 1-character strings, so there is always exactly one character in your function loop.

So, `int()` is never called on any non-digit, because the [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) filters out any character that is not a digit.

You can see what happens if you use a simple `for` loop instead:

```
>>> string = 'foo 42 bar 8 1'
>>> for character in string:
...     if character.isdigit():
...         print(character)
...
4
2
8
1
```

Because `str.isdigit()` only returns true for strings (here consisting of just one character each) contains *only* digits.

Instead of a `for` loop, you could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to produce a list:

```
>>> [c for c in string if c.isdigit()]
['4', '2', '8', '1']
```

Now it is easy to add that `int()` call and see the difference:

```
>>> [int(c) for c in string if c.isdigit()]
[4, 2, 8, 1]
```

Because only digits are passed through, `int()` always works, it is never called on a letter.

Your function then uses `sum()` on those values, so for my sample string, adding up 4 + 2 + 8 + 1 is 15:

```
>>> sum(int(c) for c in string if c.isdigit())
15
```